# How should I fetch data from another collection and join with the result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an endpoint which gives me a list of all Profiles available, now I have a Post Schema & Profile Schema, I want to add a list of posts that specific users have made to my result

**Code present in endpoint**

```java
 const profiles = await Profile.find()
            .populate('user', [
                'name',
                'avatar'
            ])
```

**Profile Schema**

```java
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    post: [],
    ........
```

**Post Schema**

```java
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ........
```

**Response**

```java
[
    {
        "social": {
            "youtube": "https://youtube.com/.",
            "twitter": "https://twitter.com/.",
            "facebook": "https://fb.com/."
        },
        "post": [],          //This should populate
        "skills": [
            "HTML",
            "CSS",
            "PHP",
            "Ruby"
        ],
        "_id": "5ced6cb9e3f7485ee2cb0445",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5ced02551b60fe20afc72a32",
            "name": "John abc",
            "avatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/1f9d9a9efc2f523b2f09629444632b5c?s=200&r=pg&d=mm"
        },
        "status": "Developer",
        "experience": [
            {
                "current": true,
                "_id": "5ceebb30bb0c667b85a94f97",
                "from": "2010-08-09T18:30:00.000Z",
                "description": "lorem ipasum"
            }
        ],
        "date": "2019-05-28T17:15:37.755Z",
        "__v": 30,
        "bio": "I am dev",
        "education": [
            {
                "current": false,
                "_id": "5cf0c1dc6b8dc33cd68be560",
                "degree": "BE",
                "from": "2005-07-09T18:30:00.000Z",
                "to": "2010-03-03T18:30:00.000Z",
                "description": "Got BE"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Expected output**

```java
[
    {
        "social": {
            "youtube": "https://youtube.com/.",
            "twitter": "https://twitter.com/.",
            "facebook": "https://fb.com/."
        },
        "post": [
                 {_id:98as98djakjbkasd,
                  text:"This is post by xyz user"
                 },
                 {_id:234oijaoijd,
                  text:"This is another post by xyz user"
                 }
                ]
        "skills": [
            "HTML",
            "CSS",
            "PHP",
            "Ruby"
        ],
        "_id": "5ced6cb9e3f7485ee2cb0445",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5ced02551b60fe20afc72a32",
            "name": "John abc",
            "avatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/1f9d9a9efc2f523b2f09629444632b5c?s=200&r=pg&d=mm"
        },
        .....
```

I want to populate posts done by the same user, what changes are needed to be done in endpoint code.

I am new to mongoose, upon searching for solutions I found `aggregate` could be useful but it cannot be used like `.find().aggregate([...])`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to join in MongoDB would defeat the purpose of using MongoDB. As we first think about our use case then decide database and schema. You could however use [DBref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) and write your own application code.

Another thing you can alter your schema into a single collection and use [embedded document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference)

It's always a suggestion of MongoDB that avoid join in our query!

Comment: Wouldn't ```aggregate() or $match/$lookup``` will be useful here

Comment: Yes, It can be done by aggregation lookup pipeline. One is localField and foreignField concept it helps in merging the results makes life easy. So kindly use #use-lookup-with-mergeobjects if there is any relation in your data set of both collections. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-mergeobjects